# New authentificaion protocol of MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 8.0.4 there is a new client <-> server authentificaion protocol. When I try to connect from my client to the MySQL server, the MySQL server responses:

> Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Until now, I connect to the MySQL directly from my application - without the libMySQL.dll. So I communicate without a library directly via TCP/IP. Now I have to implement the new authentification. Where do I get information about the new client server protocol?

Inside the [MySQL Internals Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/) I don't find information about it. Is this not update to date?

Other MySQL client applications are having the same problem. So it's not a problem of my developing language - it's a problem of the client <-> server protocol of the MySQL server. (I'm using Delphi and my client library has more than 3000 lines of code.)

I'm looking for a solution working with each MySQL server - not only for my one. So changing the password storing is not a solution for me.

Comment: What programming language (application code) do you use to connect to mysql ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: I wrote my application in Delphi.

Comment: @Tahtu Which library are you using in Delphi to connect to the MySQL server? Is there an update for that library that it supports MySQL 8?

Comment: @Progman: No library - I wrote my own library. And now, I have to update it. (I access directly via TCP/IP to the MySQL server)

Comment: @Tahtu Which version was the MySQL server before the update?

Comment: @Tahtu What about https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/authentication-method.html, does the "secure password authentication" not work?

Comment: @Progman: With MySQL 8.0.1 all was fine. With 8.0.12 I can't login with the given error message.

Comment: @Progman: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/sha256.html shows me to use CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH. I still use it and get the mentioned error message. So I have to explain the server how I encode the password. How can I tell this to the server and how can I encode the password on the new way, starting with 8.0.4 (or something like that).

Comment: @Tahtu According to https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1054 in "How The Authentication works" it looks like the server is sending the authentication method being used in the handshake. Maybe you need to ask in the MySQL forum itself or you add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question which shows how you connect to the MySQL server, send/parse the requests/responses and how you get the error message (you might need to do this in the MySQL forum post as well).

Comment: @Progman: Your link shows to the server 5.5 - but there is a new auth. method in 8.0.

Comment: @Tahtu It looks like `caching_sha2_password` is now the default authentication method used at 8.0.4 which your client doesn't know about. Please edit your question to include the source code (preferable as MCVE) on how you connect to the MySQL server, send/parse the requests/responses, how you get the current error message, how you deal with the server response after connecting and how you try to change the current user for the login process. Not sure about the upgrade process of MySQL but you might need to reset the user passwords because of the new default authentication plugin.

Comment: @Progman: My client library is more than 3000 lines of code. I don't believe I should publish it here. Yes, I need further detailes of the caching_sha2_password.

Comment: @Tahtu Thats why you should provide a "MCVE", not your whole 3000 lines of code. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/sha256.html shows how you create the hash for authentication, but since its very spare you might want to peek in https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/68c54371821c87ff40a773acc127ce357b46a5ae/Source/MySql.Data/Authentication/CachingSha2AuthenticationPlugin.cs how the mysql client library is doing it (or from another mysql connector you are more comfortable reading with).

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL 8 the default authentication is now SHA-2 which you can read about here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html

You should probably use it however if you don't wish to you can change the default to the legacy mode for any given user with something like this:

```
ALTER USER myUser IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD';
```

That will force the old method if you're looking for a quick fix.

You don't (I suspect) want to start altering the source code for your client because then you have a branched version of it which is going to make deployment and updating on your servers a nightmare. You're better off simply waiting until such time as a new version of your client software is available that supports the new method.

MySQL source is here:
https://github.com/mysql

Comment: I write my own client software. So I can't wait for an other developer - the users of my software are waiting for me.

Comment: In that case you have potentially quite a difficult problem. Though fortunately not many people should be running 8.0 in production environments yet. You will need to add SHA2 support to your application, I believe. In the meantime, you will have to make MySQL_native_password authentication a requirement of your software.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the information you wanted about the source for MySQL. I'm afraid I probably can't help further.

Comment: Strange the code of libMySQL.cc. And I can't find the mysql_real_connect method, which I need.

Comment: At this point, I would start asking in the MySQL developers community. It's more specific than StackOverflow and you're more likely to find help. Sorry I couldn't help more.